# bootsrap grid system distort on mobile view

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, mobile

```
  <div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6" >
           <div id="carousel"> <br><br><br>
          <!-- <div id="wrapper">-->
            <img src="<?php echo $pic1 ;?>" alt="c1" width="300" height="495"/>
            <img src="<?php echo $pic2 ;?>" alt="c2" width="300" height="500"  />
            <img src="<?php echo $pic3 ;?>" alt="c3" width="300" height="500" />
            </div>
        <div id="thumbnails">
            <img src="<?php echo $pic1 ;?>" alt="c1" width="100" height="100" />
            <img src="<?php echo $pic2 ;?>" alt="c2" width="100" height="100" />
            <img src="<?php echo $pic3 ;?>" alt="c3" width="100" height="100" />

        </div>
        </div>



      <div class="col-lg-6 text-right" >
     <div class="well">
        <div id="lt">
    <h2><?php echo $name ;?></h2>
    <h2>&#8377;.<?php echo $price;?></h2>
      <ul>
    <li><?php  echo strstr($screen, '<br>', true);?>cm</li>
    <li><?php echo $os; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $mem; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $sim; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $pic3 ;?></li>
    </ul>
    <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-primary" value = "Add2Kart" id = "<?php echo $id; ?>">
   </div>
       </div>
        </div>
     </div>
      </div>
```

when i shrink my browser to check the mobile view the text comes over the slider, i want the mobile details just below the mobile slider .. and if i view in desktop i can see those to side by side .. but the text coming over the slider instead below of it .. i divided  the two columns but it get distorted on mobile view. i want whenever the page loads it automatically gets adjusted according to device i used  this already.

[distorted mobile view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/15ekbvdd9bs3ce8/distorted%20mobile%20view.PNG?dl=0)

[Desktop view i want desktop view as it is](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cnn7blt644gr41h/i%20want%20this%20to%20be%20same%20%20as%20it%20is%20in%20desktop.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: Share screen shots, if possible!

Comment: please anyone ,my problem isn't solve yet

Answer (score 2):

Here you need to update bootstrap class used for  elements from

> **col-lg-6** to 
>   **col-xs-6**

also it needs to add **.img-responsive** class to both images. so that these images will be re-sized at mobile devices level but not split into two rows.

Answer (score 1):

use `<div class="col-xs-6" >` for small size devices like mobile,
and use `<div class="col-md-6" >` for medium size devices like tablet
and use `<div class="col-lg-6" >` for large devices like Laptops and Desktops

And try to overview http://getbootstrap.com/ , its bootstrap official website,its having much more explanations